# Extracting only one data in a table using select

Tags: sql, select

I have 3 tables in my database which is

table 1 (users)
userid(PK)
EmployeeName

table 2 (SubDept)
SubDeptID(PK)
Department

table 3 (SubDeptTransfer)
TransferID(PK)
userid(FK)
SubDeptID(FK)

here is my example table for Table 3

[image]
what i wanted to do is to be able to print the SubDeptID of user 100. The problem is since there are two userid of 100 its printing both. the mission is to be able to print only one data with a latter TransferID.  What could be the best select statement for the problem?

Comment: Re-tagged because your question is about a SQL statement, not PHP. You may be implementing it in PHP but your question never mentions it and it is not relevant to answering the question. What flavor of SQL might be (MySql, Oracle, etc), you might want to add that information to your question and add a tag for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is using the window function `row_number()`:

```
select transferId, userId, subDeptId
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by TransferId desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Gordon, could you explain why this approach is more efficient than something simpler like "SELECT transferId, userId, subDeptId FROM SubDeptTransfer WHERE subDeptId = 100 ORDER BY transferId DESC LIMIT 1? I'm just interested to understand when and why using this sort of partitioning scheme would be faster than an order and limit.

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  The difference was just that you correctly understood what was being asked for.  Nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like so:

```
SELECT subDeptId FROM SubDeptTransfer WHERE userId = 100 ORDER BY transferId DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: in this program im nto just referring to userid 100 but in general. what if theres the same userid as 101? how could i generalize it? or in over all not only userid100?

Comment: What do you mean, in general?  My understanding was that you wanted to return the subDeptId for a given userId.  Substitute whatever userId you want in place of the 100 in my query and you will get the matching subDeptId with the highest transferId.  Are you saying you want the result to have a row for every userId? If so, I expect Gordon Linoff's solution will work.

Comment: thank you. i tried using  what mr gordon gives and it works fine now thank you!